# Predicting classes in MNIST dataset with a Gaussian- the same prediction errors with different paramemters?

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, gaussian

I am trying to find the best c parameter following the instructions to a task that asks me to ' Define a function, fit_generative_model, that takes as input a training set (train_data, train_labels) and fits a Gaussian generative model to it. It should return the parameters of this generative model; for each label j = 0,1,...,9, where

```
   pi[j]: the frequency of that label
   mu[j]: the 784-dimensional mean vector
   sigma[j]: the 784x784 covariance matrix
```

It is important to regularize these matrices. The standard way of doing this is to add cI to them, where c is some constant and I is the 784-dimensional identity matrix. c is now a parameter, and by setting it appropriately, we can improve the performance of the model.

```
%matplotlib inline
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import gzip, os
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

if sys.version_info[0] == 2:
   from urllib import urlretrieve
else:
   from urllib.request import urlretrieve

# Downloads the dataset
def download(filename, source='http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/'):
   print("Downloading %s" % filename)
   urlretrieve(source + filename, filename)

# Invokes download() if necessary, then reads in images
def load_mnist_images(filename):
   if not os.path.exists(filename):
       download(filename)
   with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as f:
       data = np.frombuffer(f.read(), np.uint8, offset=16)
   data = data.reshape(-1,784)
   return data

def load_mnist_labels(filename):
   if not os.path.exists(filename):
       download(filename)
   with gzip.open(filename, 'rb') as f:
       data = np.frombuffer(f.read(), np.uint8, offset=8)
   return data

## Load the training set
train_data = load_mnist_images('train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz')
train_labels = load_mnist_labels('train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz')

## Load the testing set
test_data = load_mnist_images('t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz')
test_labels = load_mnist_labels('t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz')

train_data.shape, train_labels.shape
```

So I have written this code for three different C-values. they each give me the same error?

```
   def fit_generative_model(x,y):
       lst=[]
       for c in [20,200, 4000]:
           k = 10  # labels 0,1,...,k-1
           d = (x.shape)[1]  # number of features
           mu = np.zeros((k,d))
           sigma = np.zeros((k,d,d))
           pi = np.zeros(k)
           for label in range(0,k):
               indices = (y == label)
               mu[label] = np.mean(x[indices,:], axis=0)
               sigma[label] = np.cov(x[indices,:], rowvar=0, bias=1) + c*np.identity(784) # I define the identity matrix
   
           predictions = np.argmax(score, axis=1)
   
           errors = np.sum(predictions != y)
           lst.append(errors)
           print(c,"Model makes " + str(errors) + " errors out of 10000", lst)
```

Then I fit it to the training data and get these same errors:

```
       mu, sigma, pi = fit_generative_model(train_data, train_labels)
       20 Model makes 1 errors out of 10000 [1]
       200 Model makes 1 errors out of 10000 [1, 1]
       4000 Model makes 1 errors out of 10000 [1, 1, 1]
```

and to the test data:

```
mu, sigma, pi = fit_generative_model(test_data, test_labels)
20 Model makes 9020 errors out of 10000 [9020]
200 Model makes 9020 errors out of 10000 [9020, 9020]
4000 Model makes 9020 errors out of 10000 [9020, 9020, 9020]
```

What is it I'm doing wrong? the correct answer is  c=4000 which yields an error of ~4.3%.